# NSMutableArray empty after leaving View

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray, gets

I have a Mutable Array and I fill it with some strings. But when I leave the view (Navigation Controller) and reopen it, the Array is empty. My Mutable Array gets emptied, everytime I leave the view.

```
if([name_Recipe isEqualToString:@""])
{
    NSLog(@"Nothing");
}
else
{
    [favoritesArrayDetail addObject:name_Recipe];
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", favoritesArrayDetail]);
}
```

Comment: In which way are you leaving the view? Going back to the previous, to the next view?

Comment: In your `else` block, why are you creating a string from an array? If you want print out the array, `NSLog(@"Favourites Array: %@", favoritesArrayDetail)` will work.

Comment: @MikeD Thanks. Yes, I go back to previous. When I switch  the View with my Tabbar, it doesn't get emptied. Only when I leave it with the "Back" button in my Navigation Bar.

Comment: Your NSLog is needlessly complicated, `NSLog(@"%@", favoritesArrayDetail);` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you leave the view, the view controller is being released along with all of its member variables. If you want to still be able to access the array, you need yo declare it somewhere else, or make it static.

EDIT: Since viewDidLoad is called every time you go back to the view, it is resetting the array back to an empty one because of `[NSMutableArray new]`. You want to only call that line of code when the array has not yet been created.

For example, you could do:

```
if (!favoritesArrayDetail) //Only do this code if the array is nil.
    favoritesArrayDetail = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Comment: Good idea, but when I do this, it's the same problem. The array gets empied anyhow.

Comment: are you  doing `favoritesArrayDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` in the view's init or didLoad/appear or anywhere else when the view is created? If so, that is what is deleting the array and you want to only do it if the array has not been created: `if (!favoritesArrayDetail)`

Comment: Now I have `static NSMutableArray *favoritesArrayDetail;` in my m file. Before I had a property on the array, but with both, it doesn't work

Comment: I found @Jsdodgers answer very important - post where you initialize your mutable array

Comment: I initialize it between `#import` and `@implementation`, but before his post, i had a property of it in my header file and synthesized it in the implementation file.

Comment: in which method exactly is favoritesArrayDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] or favoritesArrayDetail = [[NSMutableArray new] ?

Comment: viewDidLoad. See above on your answer :)

Comment: Ok I changed it to `if (!favoritenArrayDetail) //Only do this code if the array is nil. favoritenArrayDetail = [NSMutableArray new];`, but the problem is still there. I think I have to save the array, when viewWillDisappearis called.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your array as a property.

`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *favoritesArrayDetail;`

And in viewDidLoad:

```
if (!favoritesArrayDetail)
{
    favoritesArrayDetail = [NSMutableArray new];
}
```

Comment: update your question and post your whole controller class, there is no way to help if you don't post your broken code